# Set up Kerberos Authentication with Delegation on IIS 7 w/ Windows Server 2008

Tags: authentication, iis-7, active-directory, kerberos

**Situation:**

I have a .NET asmx web service deployed on my web server. This service calls a service on another server (our SharePoint server, if that's relevant). I want to impersonate/delegate the call to the SharePoint service from my web service by using the credentials of the client.

**Problem:**

I'm getting a 401 response back from the SharePoint service when I call MY Web Service and it calls SharePoint.

**Setup:**

- My web server is running IIS 7. The app pool is running under "Network Service"
- On my Windows Server 2003 domain controller the web server has "Trusted for Delegation (Kerberos Only)" enabled.
- In ISS my app has Anonymous Authentication Disabled, Impersonation Enabled, and Windows Authentication Enabled with all three providers enabled (Negotiate:Kerberos, Negotiate, and NTLM)
- The SharePoint server is set up with Anonymous Enabled, Impersonation enabled and Windows Authentication Enabled with ONLY provider NTLM enabled.

I can see on the SharePoint logs that when I run locally in Visual Studio a username is getting passed through (and the service works correctly) but when I run it on the web server NO username is on the log file and I get a 401 error

What an I setting up wrong to make the Kerberos delegation work?

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Platform:**

Using IIS7 this is what I did on BOTH servers. The first server and the second that we want the Kerberos authentication to "hop" to.

**Step 1:**

For the IIS site that has the services in it that you are calling (on each server) go into IIS manager, click on the site on the left under Connections and open up the "Authentication" section under IIS. Set "ASP.NET Impersonation" to Enabled and 'Windows Authentication" to Enabled. All other options under Authentication (Ananymous, Forms, etc.) should be be set to Disabled.

Under "Windows Authentication" right click and select "Providers". Set the only provider to be "Negotiate:Kerberos" (This forces Kerberos. If you want, after you get Kerberos working you can use both the "Negotiate" and "NTLM" providers and remove "Negotiate:Kerberos" so that clients unable to do Kerberos can connect. Note: I currently have mine set to "Negotiate" and "NTLM" and it seems to work)

Under "Windows Authentication" right click and select "Advanced Settings". Uncheck the "Enable Kernal-mode" box. (My Extended Protection option was set to off, didn't try anything else)

**Step 2:**

For each server you have to set up SPNs. The SPNs would be the following (either A OR B):

**A:**

If your app pool is running under an IDENTITIY that is a DOMAIN ACCOUNT add the following SPNs to THAT DOMAIN ACCOUNT on the domain controller

```
http/COMPUTER_NETBIOS_NAME 
http/COMPUTER_NETBIOS_NAME.FULLY_QUALIFIED_DOMAIN_NAME 
http://COMPUTER_NETBIOS_NAME.FULLY_QUALIFIED_DOMAIN_NAME
```

(if your not running on the default port, also add an additional 3 entries with the port name attached: http/COMPUTER_NETBIOS_NAME:PORT etc.)

**B:**

If your app pool is running under the IDENTITY "NetworkService" then add the same SPNs as above except replace "http" with "HOST" BUT ADD THEN TO COMPUTER_NETBIOS_NAME on your domain controller.

I'm still working to implement this in production, but this is what works for me in my Test environment. I'll keep this updated as I find out more.

**Note:**

This works if you are using the COMPUTER_NETBIOS_NAME directly in the url when you connect. If you are using a alias (www.mysite.mydomain.com) or the IP address directly this will not work. I believe, although I have not fully tested it, that you would have to folle the steps above but replace COMPUTER_NETBIOS_NAME with the alias or IP address when adding the SPNs. (or add it with both the netbios and the alias/ip, not really sure)

Also, if you get an error about a setting not being valid for integrated... after you turn on the "ASP.NET Impersonation" then you might need to add

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

to your web.config in the system.webServer section

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Move `Negotiate` to the top of the Providers' list. And, in the `applicationHost.config` file usually under `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`, add `useKernelMode="true" useAppPoolCredentials="true"` to the `<windowsAuthentication>` tag under the `<location>` tag for your application, like below:

```
<location path="YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="true" useAppPoolCredentials="true">
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: I can give this a try on Monday, however, in IIS manager, for my app, I have the useAppPoolCredentials set to true, and useKernalMode set to true, and I have tried it with every combination of providers. And I have tried it with both the kernal and appPool false and every other combination I can think of. But I'll try making these settings in the config

Comment: I have read some documentation saying that you have to use Negotiate:Kerberos and actually set the userKernalMode to false. But as soon as I set it to false I can't access the website at all.

Comment: I don't use Kerberos provider. Just Negotiate and NTLM.

Comment: And you have gotten it to work? With some web service calling another on a different server with the client credentials?

Comment: No, mine is not a web service.

Comment: It's a web application that allows users upload and save files onto another server.

Comment: hum, ya I think that still has to make the same type of hop I'm trying to make here. I'll give this a try and let you know. Do you know if it's issue that on the second server it's only set up for NTLM?

Comment: I can check the settings on the second server on Tuesday. I'll let you know.

Comment: I just checked my applicationHost.config file, it matched what you have there. Let me know what setting you have on your second server for the providers. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Also, did you set up the first server in AD to be allowed for Delegation, like this page mentions? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee675779.aspx If so, which setting did you use? Unconstrained delegation, Constrained delegation (Kerberos only) or Constrained delegation (any protocol)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have admin access to the other server. I can't check its settings.

Comment: After reading something like 300 articles I came across this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx Of course it doesn't outline the steps for enabling Kerberos on the second server... haha

Comment: Not yet, I also found this article: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5948.sharepoint-2010-configuring-kerberos-authentication.aspx and I'm working on trying to follow the steps to get it up on our DEV SharePoint server. Right now, if I enabled Kerberos the site wont even load, there is a number of configuration steps outlined in this article that I need to work with my infrastructure team to try out. I'mm keep you posted.

Comment: I got it to work. With a LOT of steps as I outlined in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Delegation requires Kerberos.  You'll have to make the SharePoint server support authentication with Kerberos.

Comment: Does it require `Negotiate:Kerberos` or just `Negotiate`? I just want to clarify because @ataravati mentioned he is not using `Kerberos`. Also, to use `Kerbero`s on the SharePoint server do I just need to add `Negotiate:Kerberos` to the provider list? should I remove `NTLM`, is there anything I need to install or otherwise set up?

Comment: @kralco626 My experience with delegation is with my custom WCF app which talks to Active Directory, so I can't really help with the details with IIS/SharePoint.  `Negotiate` lets Windows figure out whether to use `NTLM` or `Kerberos`, and I think `Negotiate:Kerberos` forces `Kerberos`.

Comment: Just as a general update these are two articles I'm using to try to get Kerberos set up on SharePoint: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5948.sharepoint-2010-configuring-kerberos-authentication.aspx and http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Kerberos-Sharepoint-Environment.html