# EWS Managed: Root Element is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm developing an Exchange Web Services Managed API client on top of ASP.NET MVC. Everything worked until we installed the latest Exchange CU update yesterday. Then I periodically got "target principal name is incorrect" errors after some time on my web server when connecting to EWS. These could get fixed temporarily by restarting the web server.

I then used this post to configure Kerberos correctly: [Set up Kerberos Authentication with Delegation on IIS 7 w/ Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025169/set-up-kerberos-authentication-with-delegation-on-iis-7-w-windows-server-2008)

Now I am stuck with the following error that I never had before:

```
Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
[XmlException: Root element is missing.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +88
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +1383
   System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read() +153
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read() +63
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read(XmlNodeType nodeType) +44
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadXmlDeclaration(EwsServiceXmlReader reader) +54

[ServiceRequestException: The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML.]
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadXmlDeclaration(EwsServiceXmlReader reader) +165
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadSoapFault(EwsServiceXmlReader reader) +43
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException) +413
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) +139
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request) +573
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute() +42
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindAppointments(FolderId parentFolderId, CalendarView calendarView) +104
```

Because this is a managed version of the Exchange Web Services API I have nothing to do with the XML Requests and Responses directly. It's basically a black box for me. As you can see from the error, it occurs when calling for data from EWS.

Comment: do you have trace enabled? 
Looks like something you need to debug by looking at the XMLs see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633676(v=exchg.80).aspx for more details on tracing

Comment: We had the same error after migrating the mailboxes to a new server due to deleting the old server/database and CAS caching. "Root element is missing" is actually hiding the real error (server returning a 500 error and no content), using tracing maybe (or fiddler with https decryption) you can look at the headers returned by the webservices and see the actual error code/message.  For us, this led to: https://pickettsproblems.wordpress.com/tag/x-caserrorcode-databaseguidnotfound/    and this: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/cherish-old-exchange-databases-avoid-pesky-databaseguidnotfound-error